# Why does read and writing have to be separated for configparser?

Tags: python, configparser

My code

```
with open('config.ini', 'a+') as fp:   # have tried r+ also, same result
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read(fp)   # have tried config.read_string(fp.read()) also
    print(config.sections())   # this is [] every time somehow
    if 'section' not in config:
        config.add_section('section')
    section = config['section']
    section['option'] = 'value'
    config.write(fp)
```

and the ini file, instead of getting overwritten, keeps on appending these same duplicate entries and I get no exception either. A Section being a dictionary should not have this type of behavior.

But when I separate read and writing code like this it works as expected:

```
config = ConfigParser()
config.read(fp)
with open('config.ini', 'w') as fp:
    if 'section' not in config:
        config.add_section('section')
    section = config['section']
    section['option'] = 'value'
    config.write(fp)
```

I think this has something to do with the position of `fp`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the file pointer, But the file mode matters(`"a+"` only append the contents). If you want to overwrite use `w` instead.

Comment: Basically you can ask the same question for `json` module/files. If you don't want to append, don't use mode `a`

Comment: @buran I did want to append that's why I used `a+` or `r+`, since the config file is desktop.ini and might contain data I should not touch, however the code below works so its fine

Comment: mode `a+` (append) has a specific meaning in the context of file operations. If you think in the terms of dict (ConfigParser is in its essence a mapping) then you perform an update :-) Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+ in built-in open function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function)

Comment: @buran Infact I thought about trying `a+` or `r+` after reading a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function/30566011#30566011). I can understand `a+` not working but what about `r+`?

Comment: `r+` mode works just fine. With your code - you open the file in `r+` mode, the stream is positioned at the beginning. You read the file (stream is at the end), You write - it appends at the end. If you want to reposition the stream at the beginning use `fp.seek(0)` just before write operation. Note, this may lead to very unexpected results - e.g. only partially overwrite data. So don't use it for this usecase